# Trying to call a php page throught ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

On submit alert is working but inside ajax code not working.
value store in var and go to ajax page where i trying to use mysql insert query but its not working properly. I after ajax success result is not display, For a sec ajax file name shows in NET (error console)

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
$('#submit').click(function(){
var project_ID = $('#project_name').val();
var accommodation=$('#accommodation').val();
var no_of_floors=$('#no_of_floors').val();
var no=$('#no').val();
 if(project_ID==''){
    alert('Select Project Name');
}
if(accommodation==''){
    alert('Select Accomodation Scale');
}
 if($('#typeI').prop('checked')){
    var type1=$('#typeI').val();
    }
if($('#typeII').prop('checked')){
    var type2=$('#typeII').val();
    }
if($('#typeIII').prop('checked')){
    var type3=$('#typeIII').val();
    }
if($('#typeIV').prop('checked')){
    var type4=$('#typeIV').val();
    }
    if(project_ID!="" && accommodation!='') 
   {
    $.ajax({url:"villa_Accomo_type.php?project_ID="+project_ID
   +"&accommodation="+accommodation+"&type1="+type1+"&type2="+type2
   +"&type3="+type3+"&type4="+type4+"&no_of_floors="+no_of_floors+"&no="+no,
      success:function(result){
          res=result;
        alert(res);

     }

}); 
   }
 });
 });
```

AJAX PAGE

```
    <?php
$project_ID    = $_GET['project_ID'];
$accommodation = $_GET['accommodation'];
$type1         = $_GET['type1'];
$type2         = $_GET['type2'];
$type3         = $_GET['type3'];
$type4         = $_GET['type4'];
$no_of_floors  = $_GET['no_of_floors'];
$no            = $_GET['no'];

echo $insert = "insert into villas_scale (project_id,scale,type,
  no_of_floors,no)    values('$project_ID',
'$accommodation','$type1','$no_of_floors','$no')";
mysql_query($insert);

echo $insert2 = "insert into villas_scale (project_id,scale,
 type,no_of_floors,no) values('$project_ID',
'$accommodation','$type2','$no_of_floors','$no')";
mysql_query($insert2);

echo $insert3 = "insert into villas_scale (project_id,scale,
  type,no_of_floors,no) values('$project_ID',
'$accommodation','$type3','$no_of_floors','$no')";
mysql_query($insert3);
echo $insert4 = "insert into villas_scale (project_id,scale,
 type,no_of_floors,no) values('$project_ID',
'$accommodation','$type4','$no_of_floors','$no')";
mysql_query($insert4);

?>
```

Comment: try to find error in console

Comment: call the url in your browser and check your response

Comment: Your code is **very vulnerable** towards SQL injection. [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**pink box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: what is this `echo $insert =` ? please go and learn how to use variables

Comment: @samitha `echo $var = 'value'` is the same as `$var = 'value'; echo 'value';`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to edit so many errors in your code .[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cBT6/)

```
var no = $('#no').val();
if (project_ID === '') {
    alert('Select Project Name');
}
if (accommodation === '') {
    alert('Select Accomodation Scale');
}
if ($('#typeI').prop('checked')) {
    var type1 = $('#typeI').val();
}
if ($('#typeII').prop('checked')) {
    var type2 = $('#typeII').val();
}
if ($('#typeIII').prop('checked')) {
    var type3 = $('#typeIII').val();
}
if ($('#typeIV').prop('checked')) {
    var type4 = $('#typeIV').val();
}
if (project_ID !== "" && accommodation !== '') {
    $.ajax({
        url: "villa_Accomo_type.php",//This should the url where you send data
        type: 'GET',
        data: project_ID = "project_ID" + project_ID + " & accommodation = " + accommodation + " & type1 = " + type1 + " & type2 = " + type2 + " & type3 = " + type3 + " & type4 = " + type4 + " & no_of_floors = " + no_of_floors + " & no = " + no, // here you need the specify your serialize object 
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);

        }

    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, its still not working, getting below error     Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead.

Comment: @user3535570 Make some effort to research by your own, that's not an error, that's a warning. There are many topics relative to this, use google...

Comment: @A.Wolff yes.I just edited him jquery code.There are many errors in php too.

Comment: @h2oooo as mentioned use http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers tutorial

Comment: @samitha Its Start Working after some changing Thanks